# Django-allauth - is there a way to automatically send an email after account is verified

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

We recently took over a project that was developed in Django, which uses allauth. We are hoping to send out some additional information to users once they have signed up and confirmed their email address, is there a default/native way to do this in django-allauth? At the moment the system uses `email_confirmation_message.txt` to configure the email for users to confirm their email address, but we couldn't find something similar once the account is confirmed.

Comment: There's a signal provided when the email address is confirmed: https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/signals.html

Comment: That's, that's given me enough to go onto making my own functions to process the data and send the required emails

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a way: [django-allauth emits signals](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/signals.html) in various phases of the user signup process, including a signal when the user confirms their email:

```
allauth.account.signals.email_confirmed(request, email_address)
```

Adding a [listener](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/signals/) for that signal should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

As dirkgroten mentioned, you should use the `email_confirmed` signal. However, this signal is triggered both when a user confirms their address after signing up and when they add new email addresses. To only execute code in the former case, you can check if the user hasn't logged in yet:

```py
from allauth.account.models import EmailAddress
from allauth.account.signals import email_confirmed

@receiver(email_confirmed)
def on_email_confirmed(email_address: EmailAddress, **kwargs):
    user = email_address.user
    if user.last_login is None:
        # New user - do something here
```